# JavaScript VM optimization on strings concatenation

Tags: javascript

Some time ago declarations like the following were defined by poor performance:

```
var a = "my" +
"very" +
"very" +
"long" +
"string" +
"and" + 
"even" +
"longer";
```

I was told that every subsequent `+` operation causes an additional string to be created since they are immutable. At least, once that was an issue in Java programming language (mind `StringBuffer` vs. `String`).

I am talking about the more-or-less recent versions of the browsers of course.

The question is about JavaScript now: is it still not recommended or the runtime can squack (or should I say optimize) the issue like one above in milliseconds without any performance overhead?

Comment: You can do your own js performance tests on jsperf.com.  For example http://jsperf.com/string-concat-js which seems to indicate that it doesn't matter with modern browsers.

Comment: @James: did it, looks I am correct (it took a very short time), but still curious for the global wisdom answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number of points:

- What you cite was never a performance problem in Java; the compiler always optimized it using `StringBuffer`. Problems only arise when appending to a variable in a loop.
- Java and JavaScript have absolutely nothing to do with each other.
- The JavaScript runtime would have to work very hard to **de**-optimize the issue until it takes milliseconds. On a modern CPU, a millisecond is an eternity.
- Premature optimization. Don't.
- Profile/Benchmark before you optimize. Here's [numbers from someone who did](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/05/09/string-performance-an-analysis/), but note that the results are 3 years old and thus meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

This makes more sense if you're concatenating a large amount of string values:

```
str = [
    'string1',
    'string2',
    'string3',
    'string4',
    'etc.'
].join( '' );
```

Comment: @BreakPhreak What do you mean?

Comment: in the lines (like in my example) where the object is declared at its first time (and not mutated afterwards). am I clear enough, please?

Comment: @BreakPhreak That doesn't make a difference. This `var x; x = ...;` is equivalent to this `var x = ...;`.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a simple implementation of the StringBuffer behaviour using JavaScript:

```
function StringBuffer() {
   this.buffer = [];
}

StringBuffer.prototype.append = function append(string) {
   this.buffer.push(string);
   return this;
 };

 StringBuffer.prototype.toString = function toString() {
   return this.buffer.join("");
 };

 var buf = new StringBuffer();

 buf.append("hello");
 buf.append("world");

 alert(buf.toString());
```

Source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/72429b15-73e2-4b4e-9288-9e1dfd47858b/

Comment: Well, my question is more about the concatenation in **declaration** line. The optimisations there can be peanuts for the modern JS engines.